How does the parameter const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args get its value at the C++ level?
Reading the source code and finding different functions that can be called from the js code, for example new TCP, it is not entirely clear how the C++ level accepts arguments to its level for a specific bound function.
For example, this js call is bound
new TCP(TCPConstants.SERVER)

with the following code on С++
void TCPWrap::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  // This constructor should not be exposed to public javascript.
  // Therefore we assert that we are not trying to call this as a
  // normal function.
  CHECK(args.IsConstructCall());
  CHECK(args[0]->IsInt32());
  Environment* env = Environment::GetCurrent(args);

  int type_value = args[0].As<Int32>()->Value();
  TCPWrap::SocketType type = static_cast<TCPWrap::SocketType>(type_value);

  ProviderType provider;
  switch (type) {
    case SOCKET:
      provider = PROVIDER_TCPWRAP;
      break;
    case SERVER:
      provider = PROVIDER_TCPSERVERWRAP;
      break;
    default:
      UNREACHABLE();
  }

  new TCPWrap(env, args.This(), provider);
}

That is, I want to understand how the C++ level const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args is initialized for the bound function, thanks.

Here void TCPWrap::Initialize(Local<Object> target... creates an object template with methods open, bind, connect... and TCPWrap::New is called on an object instantiation/construction.

@3CxEZiVlQ Could you give a more detailed answer? I would like to consider all the steps in more detail.

All that you're asking about happens at the call point  i.e. in the expression new TCP(TCPConstants.SERVER).   There are several possibilities, depending on the type of TCPConstants.SERVER (which you haven't specified).  One possibility - if it is an object of a type that can be implicitly converted to FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>, then a temporary (unnamed)  FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> is created, a reference to that temporary is passed and, when the new expression completes, the temporary is destroyed.

@Peter Okay. But what to do when more than one argument is passed from js? And in general, C++ function signature is always one, which represents a specific structure. That's why I ask, where, when and how does the FunctionCallbackInfo structure initialization occur? If you can, write a detailed answer that can clarify my question, thx.

In between JavaScript and your C++ code sits the JavaScript interpreter (here, V8). It is this interpreter that packs the arguments from JavaScript into FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> structure, then passes that structure to your callback. If you really want to know how FunctionCallbackInfo is constructed, you'd need to look into V8's source code.

If more than one argument is passed, then TCP must have a constructor that accepts three arguments (otherwise the expression will be a diagnosable error - i.e. the code won't compile).   Then my previous comment applies to all three arguments.

Re: what to do when there are multiple arguments. The code you show accesses the one and only argument as args[0]. I imagine that, if there are multiple arguments, you can similarly access them as args[1], args[2] and so on. There's also args.Length() method to let you know how many argumens there are.

@IgorTandetnik I wouldn't have asked this question without trying to read the V8 source code in node.js. My question is very clear, I ask to show the connection with FunctionCallbackInfo. When calling a function in js, we don't call the same-name function from C++. There is a layer where calling the same-name function in C++ gets the FunctionCallbackInfo structure. The most sensible comment was the first one. But no one dared to show the process of initializing this structure, although for those who know it's trifles.

Codesearch finds a single call site of the FunctionCallbackInfo constructor, in api-arguments-inl.h. And that's right before the embedder-provided callback is invoked with this FunctionCallbackInfo instance.
You'll likely next wonder where values_, argv_, and argc_ are coming from. The answer to that is only a few codesearch clicks away, I'll let you explore the code yourself. You should be able to trace it one step deeper, and then you're at the "magic" boundary where code generated by V8 uses custom-tailored assembly to call out to precompiled C++ functions, so you won't be able to trace it any further by following regular C++ constructs like classes and calls.
(If you're curious about the deeper details, look for Builtins::Generate_CEntry in builtins-x64.cc, but I doubt that that will be particularly insightful.)

Interesting. But I can't figure out when the call to the FunctionCallbackInfo constructor occurs, I want to understand where TCPWrap::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) is called with the FunctionCallbackInfo structure that is passed to it. Obviously not from the js code since the signatures are too different. I need your hint.

@MaximPro I already posted the link to that in my answer: the line FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> info(values_, argv_, argc_); is the FunctionCallbackInfo constructor call, and a few lines below in f(info);, f is a pointer to the TCPWrap::New function. All of that happens when the respective JavaScript function is executed; as I also said before calling out from JIT-compiled code for JavaScript to C++ happens via the "CEntry" builtin, whose job is to bridge the different calling conventions.

ok. If the CallOrConstruct operation is called when the corresponding function is executed (in this example new TCP()), then there should be a recognizable entry in the call stack before the CallOrConstruct operation. I've walked through many ways that call CallOrConstruct and kept running into dead ends. For example HandleApiCallAsFunctionOrConstructorDelegate has a call to CallOrConstruct, but as we move up the call stack we hit a macro with BUILTIN(HandleApiCallAsConstructorDelegate). And I'm stumped, I can't analyze the code any further.

When we call new TCP() from js, we don't immediately jump to f(info); being in the CallOrConstruct, we go through specific function calls. So what would be the entry point for the call to new TCP() in the C++ code that would lead us to CallOrConstruct?

@MaximPro Yes, that's why I wrote "you won't be able to trace it any further by following regular C++ constructs like classes and calls". JIT-compiled code calls (via the "CEntry" stub) the function defined by BUILTIN(HandleApiConstruct). You won't see a proper call stack because GDB doesn't understand V8's generated code, and you won't see callers in C++. Any function defined by BUILTIN(...) or RUNTIME_FUNCTION(...) is an entry point into C++ from JIT-generated code.

Great, and now the very last question, where is the point where JIT compilation is launched, which will subsequently call the BUILTIN(HandleApiConstruct) macro (sure in context of the new TCP() call)? Here I don’t even know where to look.

@MaximPro It's a complex system because there are multiple compilers. TieringManager::OnInterruptTick is probably a good place to get started. Spoiler: none of these compilers (nor anything else in V8) knows what new TCP() is or does; to V8 that's just an opaque embedder-provided function. Have fun with your explorations, this rabbit hole goes very deep :-)
